# How to refactor a core data model to make two existing entities inherit from a new abstract entity

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, core-data, migration

With this version of an iPhone app, I'm trying to create a new core data model version in which I'm taking two existing entities and changing them to inherit from a brand new abstract entity. I'm also trying to move several of the shared properties from these entities onto the new abstract entity.

When I run on an existing version of the app I get a `NSInternalInconsistencyException`

```
Cannot merge multiple root entity source tables into one destination entity root table
```

Up until this version of the app I've gotten away with "lightweight" migration. Does this exception mean that I'll need to create a Mapping Model?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I've solved the problem. I'm going be detailed here so other people can use this as a resource. I'm not completely sure about the inner workings of core data, but it seemed to choke when trying to create a new abstract entity and have two existing entities merge into it. So the solution I came up with was to ditch the old entities and create 3 brand new ones and create a mappingmodel to map data from the old entities onto the new ones.

Given the following entities that need to inherit from a new abstract entity.

- `Snake`
- `Mouse`

### Step 1 - create new model version

[Create a new model version](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-core_data_modeling_tool/Articles/creating_new_version.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010379-CH8) and create 3 new entities. Delete the old ones. I used different names for the new entities. I'm not sure if there's a way to accomplish this by keeping the names the same.

- `Serpent` (replaces snake)
- `Rodent` (replaces mouse)
- `Animal` (new abstract entity that the other two will use as a parent)

Note: it's possible to copy and paste properties and relationships in the model designer view. You can copy them between entities and even across model versions. Just select properties from the property list in the designer view and ⌘-C.  This is a big time saver when moving properties from the old entities onto the new abstract one.

### Step 2 - Create a Mapping Model

Use Xcode to [create a mapping model](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmMappingOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004735-SW1). In the creation dialog select the previous model version as the source and the new model version as the destination. The mapping model holds a list of entity mappings. Xcode should have automatically created one for each of the entities in your old model version. They follow the naming pattern of OldEntityToNewEntity. None of the new entities will have been created yet so you have to add them:

- SnakeToSerpent
- MouseToRodent

  (do not make one for the abstract Animal entity).

In the property inspector for each of the new mappings select the old entity as the source and the new one as the destination.

### Step 3 - map the properties

Some of the properties and relationships in each entity mapping should already be present. Any property that has the same name in both the old entity and the new one should have been automatically detected and setup correctly. You'll have to add a property mapping for any property that got moved to the abstract entity. (same with relationships and fetched properties) Just reference your old model version to make sure you included all the properties you plan to continue using.

That should be it.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to fix this issue without having to remove the old entities. I actually literally just added a mapping model to the project, selected the old model, the new one, and then ran the app and it worked fine.

Comment: Very nice!  I just had to create the Mapping Model, after making the new version, like serenn said.  Made no changes to the new model except to change the parent entity for the existing entities, after adding the new parent to the model version.

Comment: Just add mapping model select source and destination and save and wow its working perfectly.

Comment: Indeed, this answer could be made even simpler -- but I wouldn't have found my way through without it

Comment: In my case I did have to change the names entities which were made to be children in the new model. For some reason migration was working initially without changing the entity names, but later I made an unrelated change the model and that caused migration to fail unless I renamed the child entities.

Answer (score 2):

Just to make sure people are doing this properly, I followed the instructions given by Christian Schlensker including "do not make one for the abstract Animal entity" and (to continue his example), while it built and ran without the original "Cannot merge" error, my Serpent and Rodent were not recognised as subclasses of Animal on introspection.

In order to migrate properly I **did** have to create SnakeToAnimal and MouseToAnimal mappings which mapped the appropriate properties from subclass to superclass.

This may be what Christian was getting at with Step 3, but it wasn't entirely clear to me given his comment "do not make one for the abstract Animal entity" previously, as this is exactly what I had to do.

Comment: Could you walk me through the process of actually adding these mappings? I've added my Mappings but in the editor the destination attributes aren't available in "Attribute Mappings" (it just says "No Value" in the dropdown). I have set the destination and source of the mappings that I am attempting to add.