# Cannot add Destination Attribute to Entity Mapping from Child to (newly created) Parent Entity

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

As per [How to refactor a core data model to make two existing entities inherit from a new abstract entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250975/how-to-refactor-a-core-data-model-to-make-two-existing-entities-inherit-from-a-n?noredirect=1&lq=1), I am trying to create a mapping model that maps two children entities to their newly created parent entity.

I can add the "copy" mappings from the old to new versions of the same entities (i.e. EntryToEntry), but when I try to create a new mapping ChildToParent, I am unable to define the destination attributes:

[image: Mappings editor with problem shown]

I have added the source and destination Entities to the Mapping. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I would recommend avoiding parent-child entities in core data I have found that they don't work very well and are not worth the trouble.

Comment: @jon Can you elaborate on what you mean by "they don't work very well and are not worth the trouble", or point me towards a resource that does?